# How to find Age when column data type is smallint

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am trying to get each users age. I provided sample data above. The birth_year column is a smallint data type. How can I accomplish this I have tried so many ways but I have never worked with PostgreSQL before.

Comment: how can you get the age, knowing only a birth year?..

Comment: why smallint and not date type?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: ah... amount of year passed since birth, not the age. Hm - is it surprising only for me? :) and again I was born in 1980 July - I'm 37, if in December - I'm 36... Still can't get it - how you get age from year of birth?

Comment: @VaoTsun you can subtract current year minus birth year to get a persons age. This data was passed to me as read only so unfortunately I can't change the data types otherwise I would have set it up differently

Comment: @cpat21please read the comment above

Comment: If this is Postgres, why do I see MySQL tag?

Answer (score 3):

you can't get age from year of birth.

example:

```
t=# select (extract(year from now()) - 1980) as age;
 age
-----
  37
(1 row)
```

but If I was born in December - I'm 36... (today is October)

Answer (score 1):

If the age is the current year minus the birth year, then:

```
select (extract(year from now()) - birth_year) as age
```